# Why carousel not working when I have all the parameters in?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to use the carousel example from bootstrap, but for some reason my carousel at the top is not working, and I am not sure what the issues is? I tried searching youtube videos and stacks but nothing shows me how to fix the issue of not scrolling. I think I might be missing a dependency? Someone must have had this issue before, please advise new coding..

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/carousel/">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<main role="main">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>




  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>&copy; 2017-2019 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.4/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've just copied+pasted the HTML from the Bootstrap demo pages, including their relative paths to the CSS and JS files. This is the issue - you need to fix those paths so they work on *your own* site. You can use CDN versions of jQuery and Bootstrap to achieve this; note the first three lines:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main role="main">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>&copy; 2017-2019 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>
```